# How to group by on a highest value

Tags: mysql, group-by

So, for example i've got the following table;

```
          ID                 COUNTRY               VALUE
--------------------- -------------------- --------------------
1                      India               12000
2                      India               11000
3                      UK                  11000
4                      India               15000
5                      Canada              11000
```

And I would like to group by Country but only have the country with the highest value show up, if I would just use a group by query like:

```
SELECT * FROM countries GROUP BY country
```

I would get;

```
          ID                 COUNTRY               VALUE
--------------------- -------------------- --------------------
1                      India               12000
3                      UK                  11000
5                      Canada              11000
```

Where the value for india would be 12000. I would like the query to group on the highest value for the group by on country like:

```
          ID                 COUNTRY               VALUE
--------------------- -------------------- --------------------
3                      UK                  11000
4                      India               15000
5                      Canada              11000
```

So it's grouped on the highest value which is 15000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the MAX aggregate function.

```sql
select
  country,
  max(value) value
from countries
group by
  country
```

See the [live example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4e9338/5).

Edit: The original solution was only correct due to the nature of the data. I've removed the ID from the first query, to correct the mistake. Here is another solution (based on [@Juan Carlos Oropeza](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3470178/juan-carlos-oropeza)'s work - thank you) that will return the ID and eliminate the ties.

```
select
  min(x.id) id,
  x.country,
  x.value
from (
  select
    c.*
  from countries c
    left join countries c1 on c.value < c1.value and c.country = c1.country
  where c1.country is null    
) x
group by
  x.country,
  x.value
;
```

See the [live example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/adaf5c/1) - I've modified the data to cover edge cases mentioned above.

Comment: This answer works aswell, how does the max(id) work and why does it select the matching id for the max(value) and not the highest id number?

Comment: That only work because the data. check this example, one small change with `row 1` having the max value and will fail http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/576ec/1

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza Ugh, I've only noticed it now. You are correct. I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/BSAOE11581)**

```
SELECT s1.ID, s1.COUNTRY, s1.VALUE
FROM countries s1
LEFT JOIN countries s2 
       ON s1.VALUE < s2.VALUE
      AND s1.COUNTRY = s2.COUNTRY
WHERE s2.COUNTRY IS NULL;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**NOTE:** But be carefull of ties. In that case you can get one random from those ties.